# PHP Session not accesible until creating useless variable?

Tags: php, session

Here is a CSS file's code...

```
<?php
session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire, private');
session_name('member');
session_start();

$_SESSION['1'] = 1;
?>
/*
<?php print_r($_SESSION);?>
*/
```

For some reason PHP won't give access to session variables unless I set a useless variable after `session_start`, how can I have access to the session without having to lame out by setting a useless session variable? Everything works fine in all other files.

Comment: try var_dump($_SESSION)

Comment: `session_start()` is all you need to access session variables

Answer (score 0):

Starting a sessions does not mean anything about its contents.

Check if `session_id()` is not `""` to be sure that session exists.
Or use `session_status()` instead to receive a more detailed callback.